# react native video component is not showing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react component which is including a video that uses react native video library. But unfortunately, it is not showing a video component. This is how my code is.

```
import React, {createRef, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import AppText from '_components/appText';
import Video, {
  OnSeekData,
  OnLoadData,
  OnProgressData,
} from 'react-native-video';
import {strings} from '_translations/i18n';
import PlayerControls from '_components/playerControls';

const navigateToCameraView = (navigation) => {
  navigation.navigate('videorecording');
};

const showControls = (state, setState) => {
  state.showControls
    ? setState({...state, showControls: false})
    : setState({...state, showControls: true});
};

const playVideo = (state, setState) => {
  console.log('Hiii>>>>>>>>');
  setState({...state, showControls: false, play: true});
};

const VideoPreview = (props) => {
  const {styles, navigation, fileName} = props;
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    fullscreen: false,
    play: false,
    currentTime: 0,
    duration: 0,
    showControls: true,
  });

  const player = createRef();
  return (
    <View style={styles.previewInnerContainer}>
      {fileName ? (
        <>
          <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
            <View style={styles.videoInnerContainer}>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => showControls(state, setState)}>
                <View>
                  <Video
                    source={{uri: fileName}}
                    controls={false}
                    style={styles.backgroundVideo}
                    ref={player}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                    paused={!state.play}
                  />
                  {state.showControls && (
                    <View style={styles.controlsOverlay}>
                      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          style={styles.touchable}
                          onPress={() => playVideo(state, setState)}>
                          <Image
                            source={require('_assets/img/play1.png')}
                            resizeMode="center"
                            style={styles.playIcon}
                          />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.videoBottomText}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigateToCameraView(navigation)}>
              <View style={styles.updateAgainContainer}>
                <Icon name="reload1" style={styles.reloadIcon} />
                <AppText styles={styles.reloadText}>
                  {strings('assetsment.reload')}
                </AppText>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigateToCameraView(navigation)}>
            <Image
              source={require('_assets/img/cmerap.png')}
              resizeMode="center"
              style={styles.camPImage}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <AppText styles={styles.camPText}>Tap to capture video</AppText>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default VideoPreview;
```

I have embedded it in another component like this.

```
<View style={styles.questionsInnerContainer}>
          <View style={styles.questionTitleView}>
            <AppText styles={styles.questionTitle}>
              {strings('assetsment.question', {id: question.questionId})}
            </AppText>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.questionTextContainer}>
            <AppText styles={styles.questionText}>{questionTitle}</AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.previewContainer}>
          <VideoPreview
            styles={styles}
            navigation={navigation}
            fileName={fileName}
          />
        </View>
```

This is my styling sheet.

```
patientView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  top: {
    height: '10%',
  },
  updateAgainContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  reloadIcon: {
    fontSize: normalize(15),
    color: '#417505',
    fontWeight: '600',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  questionsContainer: {
    height: '78%',
    // backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    // elevation: 5,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 4},
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 8,
    flex: 1,
  },
  hr: {
    marginTop: '5%',
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
    borderBottomWidth: 2.0,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginLeft: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  bottom: {
    height: '7%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  patientBottomView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  patientBottomContainerText: {
    fontSize: normalize(13),
    color: '#444444',
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  bottomLinkText: {
    fontSize: normalize(13),
    color: '#484848',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    height: '30%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: '25%',
  },
  questionsInnerContainer: {
    height: '30%',
    paddingRight: '5%',
    paddingLeft: '3%',
    paddingTop: '5%',
  },
  btnContainer: {
    paddingLeft: '5%',
    paddingRight: '5%',
    marginBottom: '12%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  emtyView: {
    height: '5%',
  },
  img: {
    width: '50%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  questionTitleView: {
    paddingBottom: '2%',
    position: 'relative',
  },
  questionTitle: {
    color: '#444444',
    fontSize: normalize(11),
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  questionTextContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#d1e5ff',
    paddingTop: '6%',
    paddingBottom: '6%',
    paddingLeft: '4%',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  questionText: {
    fontSize: normalize(13),
    color: '#444444',
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  questionsLodder: {
    width: '20%',
    height: '20%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: '50%',
  },
  previewContainer: {
    height: '50%',
    marginLeft: '10%',
    marginRight: '10%',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: '2%',
  },
  previewInnerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  camPImage: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: '-15%',
  },
  camPText: {
    color: '#444444',
    fontSize: normalize(13),
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginTop: '-25%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  answersContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: '8%',
    paddingRight: '8%',
  },
  answerContentContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingBottom: '5%',
    paddingTop: '2%',
    paddingLeft: '5%',
    paddingRight: '5%',
  },
  answerTextContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  sendButton: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#3e92ff',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginTop: 25,
    marginBottom: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  sendButtonText: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: '300',
    fontSize: normalize(15),
    textAlign: 'center',
    letterSpacing: 2,
  },
  bimage: {
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
  },
  toggle: {
    transform: [{scaleX: 1.6}, {scaleY: 1.6}],
    elevation: 90,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 3},
    shadowOpacity: 0.9,
    shadowRadius: 50,
  },
  answerText: {
    color: '#444444',
    fontWeight: '600',
    fontSize: normalize(13),
  },
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  videoContainer: {
    height: '70%',
  },
  videoInnerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#b8b8b8',
  },
  videoBottomText: {
    height: '20%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  reloadText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginLeft: '5%',
    color: '#417505',
    fontWeight: '600',
    fontSize: normalize(14),
  },
  reloadTextContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  controlOverlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  wrapper: {
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    marginTop: '28%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    flex: 3,
  },
  touchable: {
    padding: 5,
  },
  playIcon: {
    // backgroundColor: '#b8b8b8',
  },
```

I tried a lot to find out what is wrong with this. But i was unable to do so. Can someone help me to find out a solution to this problem ?. If someone can help me it is really really appreciated as I am completely help less with this.Thank you

Comment: What is the value of the `fileName` prop that you are passing?

Comment: @Rodentman87 it is mp4 type file name which is locally stored

Comment: hey, try adding width in any of these style properties backgroundVideo, videoContainer, videoInnerContainer.